# Count occurrences of item in JSON element

Tags: python, json

I'm using Python to parse the UK police API. What I want is to analyse the JSON response I'm getting in order to calculate how many times a certain offence occurs. This is an example of a response from the API.

```
{
    category: "anti-social-behaviour",
    location_type: "Force",
    location: {
        latitude: "53.349920",
        street: {
            id: 583315,
            name: "On or near Evenwood Close"
        },
        longitude: "-2.657889"
    },
    context: "",
    outcome_status: null,
    persistent_id: "",
    id: 22687179,
    location_subtype: "",
   month: "2013-03"
},
```

Using this code

```
from json import load
from urllib2 import urlopen
import json

url = "http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=53.396246&lng=-2.646960&date=2013-03"
json_obj = urlopen(url)
player_json_list = load(json_obj)

for player in player_json_list:
    crimeCategories = json.dumps(player['category'], indent = 2, separators=(',', ': '))
    print crimeCategories
```

I get a response like this

```
"anti-social-behaviour"
"anti-social-behaviour"
"anti-social-behaviour"
"anti-social-behaviour"
"drugs"
"drugs"
"burglary"
```

If I changed my for loop to

```
for player in player_json_list:
    crimeCategories = json.dumps(player['category'], indent = 2, separators=(',', ': '))
    print crimeCategories.count("drugs")
```

I then get a response like

```
0
0
0
0
1
1
0
```

Searching forums for hours hasn't helped me! Any ideas?

Answer (score 21):

You can use a collections.Counter dict with requests which becomes a couple of concise lines of code:

```
import  requests
from collections import Counter

url = "http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=53.396246&lng=-2.646960&date=2013-03"
json_obj = requests.get(url).json()

c = Counter(player['category'] for player in json_obj)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'anti-social-behaviour': 79, 'criminal-damage-arson': 12, 'other-crime': 11, 'violent-crime': 9, 'vehicle-crime': 7, 'other-theft': 6, 'burglary': 4, 'public-disorder-weapons': 3, 'shoplifting': 2, 'drugs': 2})
```

If you prefer having a normal dict then simply call dict on the Counter dict:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
c = dict(c)
pp(c)
```

```
{'anti-social-behaviour': 79,
 'burglary': 4,
 'criminal-damage-arson': 12,
 'drugs': 2,
 'other-crime': 11,
 'other-theft': 6,
 'public-disorder-weapons': 3,
 'shoplifting': 2,
 'vehicle-crime': 7,
 'violent-crime': 9}
```

You then simply access by key `c['drugs']` etc..

Or iterate over the items to print crime and count in the format you want:

```
for k, v in c.items():
    print("{} count:  {}".format(k, v)
```

Output:

```
drugs count:  2
shoplifting count:  2
other-theft count:  6
anti-social-behaviour count:  79
violent-crime count:  9
criminal-damage-arson count:  12
vehicle-crime count:  7
public-disorder-weapons count:  3
other-crime count:  11
burglary count:  4
```

Comment: Personally, I think it would look even better using `print(dict(c))`.

Comment: @martineau, added the pprint output below

Comment: This was perfect! It solved my problem so simply and explained very well so that I understand why instead of blindly copying and pasting

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary and use the crimeCategories as the key. For the value, use an integer. Try putting something like this in your loop.

```
>>> count['testing'] = count.get('testing',0) + 1
>>> count['testing']
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't storing your count anywhere. Basically you are just calling for the count of the item currently in your loop.

You will want to add each item as a key in a dictionary, and then have the value increment each time you hit an occurrence in your for loop

```
adictionary = {"drugs":0}
for player in player_list:
  if adictionary.category
    adictionary.category += 1
print adictionary.category
```

Answer (score 0):

You could aggregate the data to a mapping of category->json like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

players_by_category = defaultdict(list)
for player in players_json_list:
    players_by_category[player['category'].append(player)
```

And now you have a dictionary with a list of crimes under each category.

So to get how many crimes of a certain category happened all you need is:

```
for k, v in players_by_category.iteritems():
    print "%s: %s" (k, len(v))
```

It is extremely confusing to use `player` instead of `crime`, but whatever you see fit :)