# How to compare values within a json file [in Python]

Tags: python, json, comparison

i try to make an error prevention, in which I look if their is a double definition.

For example:

```
json1 = {
    "a": "python is good",
    "b": "i like java",
    "c": "python is good"
}
```

I want to iterate over the values and find out if I got the same value at another key.

To get a message like:
"ERROR: double definition"

Is their a good way to compare these?

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819830/count-occurrences-of-item-in-json-element/28820053

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count occurrences of item in JSON element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819830/count-occurrences-of-item-in-json-element)

Answer (score 1):

You can use length(`len()` function) to compare them.

```
len(set(json1.values())) == len(json1.values())
```

You can use this in print like this:

```
print('ERROR: double definition' if len(set(json1.values())) != len(json1.values()) else 'All good')
```

Comment: It says, 'list' object has no attribute 'values'.

Comment: @Kanat0x Can you tell me what is json1 and how do you get it(From file or not)? And real data of json1(If you can't just give sample data with the same structure)

Comment: I took json1 from a file. Thanks for your help, but I solved it.