# Python - Count occurrences of combination of values in JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file, collections

I'm using python to try and parse a `JSON` file. Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819830/count-occurrences-of-item-in-json-element), I want to count the number of occurrences for each combination of 2 values in the file:

Example JSON:

```
{ 
"first": "John",
"last": "Smith"
},
{ 
"first": "Adam",
"last": "Smith"
},
{ 
"first": "Adam",
"last": "Doe"
},
{ 
"first": "John",
"last": "Smith"
}
```

Desired Output would calculate something like this (less concerned about format more about count values and associated elements):

```
{ 
"first": "John", "last": "Smith", "count": 2
},
{ 
"first": "Adam", "last": "Smith", "count": 1
},
{ 
"first": "Adam", "last": "Doe", "count": 1
}
```

I've tried the below but it obviously only counts the unique "first" values and I'm not able to find a way to consider the second attribute "last" as
well.

```
import json
from json import load
from collections import Counter

f = open('/PathToFile')
data = load(f)
c = Counter(i ['first'] for i in data)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the tuples (first,last) in your counter:

```
Counter((i['first'], i['last']) for i in data)
```